# Disable Process Step using API in Octopus Deploy

Tags: rest, teamcity, octopus-deploy

I have been searching to disable individual process step using Octopus API. I have a project which consist 10 steps and I'm using TeamCity as a CI tool. So I have a condition where 1 step needs to be disabled (whichever I want to) when I run a build. I want to disable/skip a particular step while promoting release as well.

I was able to reach till below step which is not working

```
Add-Type -Path 'Octopus.Client.dll' 

$apikey = 'API-23H4GJ243HG2H3J423433H' # Get this from your profile
$octopusURI = 'http://localhost:9090' # Your server address

$projectName = "Demo" # Name of your project

$endpoint = new-object Octopus.Client.OctopusServerEndpoint $octopusURI,$apikey 
$repository = new-object Octopus.Client.OctopusRepository $endpoint

$Header =  @{ "X-Octopus-ApiKey" = $apikey }

$project = $repository.Projects.FindByName($projectName)

$deploymentProcess = $repository.DeploymentProcesses.Get($project.DeploymentProcessId) 

foreach ($step in $deploymentProcess.Steps) 
{ 
    if($step.Name = "DemoStep") 
    { 
        $step.Actions.IsDisabled = 'True' 
        break 
    } 
} 
$repository.DeploymentProcesses.Modify($deploymentProcess)
```

Or

```
$Body = @{ 
         IsDisabled = "True" 
          } | ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $OctopusURI/api/deploymentprocesses/deploymentprocess-Projects-21/ -Method PUT` 
 -Headers $Header -Body $Body
```

Or
Octo.exe --skip=stepname will only work in this case?

Can you please help figure out this?

Thanks, 
Imran

Comment: Have you tried using the Run Condition and setting it to a variable condition so using a variable expression?

Comment: Nice idea. I never gave thought to use it for this also. I'm using Run condition for other steps. Using it for these step will also solve my other problem. I have already created another Powershell script using Octopus.client library to remotely update variables so looks like I have everything. Thanks @benPearce

Comment: This worked for me. I also had to use another script which will be used to update variable snapshot after changing variables value just before promoting to production. I also got the working script to disable process step using Octopus.Client from Octopus Support. I'll post that script in answer.

Answer (score 2):

I got the working script to disable process step from Octopus Support [Support Link](https://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/questions/13936-disable-process-step-using-api) and I extended that script to get both Disable and Enable functionality.

```
##SETUP##
$OctopusURL = ""
$APIKey = ""
$ProjectName = ""
$StepName = ""
$DesiredAction = "Enable" #Enable or Disable

##PROCESS#
Add-Type -Path 'Octopus.Client.dll'

$endpoint = new-object Octopus.Client.OctopusServerEndpoint $OctopusURL, $apikey 
$repository = new-object Octopus.Client.OctopusRepository $endpoint

$Project = $repository.Projects.FindByName($ProjectName)
$deploymentProcess = $repository.DeploymentProcesses.Get($project.DeploymentProcessID)

$WasDeploymentProcessModified = $false

foreach ($step in $deploymentProcess.Steps) {
    foreach ($Action in $step.actions) {
        if ($Action.name -eq $StepName) {
            "Step [$StepName] found"
            if ($DesiredAction -eq "Disable") {
                if ($Action.IsDisabled -eq $false) {
                    "Disabling step [$StepName]"
                    $Action.IsDisabled = $true
                    $WasDeploymentProcessModified = $true
                }

                Else {
                    "Step was already disabled"
                }
            }
            elseif ($DesiredAction -eq "Enable") {
                if ($Action.IsDisabled -eq $true) {
                    "Enabling step [$StepName]"
                    $Action.IsDisabled = $false
                    $WasDeploymentProcessModified = $true
                }

                Else {
                    "Step was already enabled"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
if ($WasDeploymentProcessModified) {
    "Steps in the deployment process of [$ProjectName] were changed. Saving changes to database..."
    $repository.DeploymentProcesses.Modify($deploymentProcess)
}
else {
    "No step was modified for [$ProjectName]"
}
```